# Python: local variable referenced before assigment

Tags: python, variables

I'm very new to python (~1 wk). I got this error when trying to run this code, intended to be a simple game where you guess heads or tails and it keeps track of your score. Is there any way I can avoid this error? I get the error for the "attempts" variable when I run attempts += 1, but I assume I'd get it for "score" too when I do the same.

```
    import random

    coin = ['heads', 'tails']
    score = 0
    attempts = 0

def coin_flip():

    print("Heads or tails?")

    guess = input()
    result = random.choice(coin)
    print("Your guess: " + guess)
    print("Result: " + result)

    attempts += 1

    if result == guess:
        print('You guessed correctly!')
        score += 1
    else:
        print('Your guess was incorrect.')

    percentCorrect = str((score / attempts) * 100) + '%'

    print("You have " + str(score) + " correct guesses in " + str(attempts) + ' attempts.')
    print("Accuracy: " + percentCorrect)
    print('Do you want to play again?')

    if input() == 'y' or 'yes':
        return coin_flip()
    else:
        quit()


coin_flip()
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You are doing pretty good for only a week of so! Check your indentation on your first four lines. They should not be indented.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random

coin = ['heads', 'tails']
score = 0
attempts = 0

def coin_flip():
    global attempts
    global score


    print("Heads or tails?")

    guess = input()
    result = random.choice(coin)
    print("Your guess: " + guess)
    print("Result: " + result)

    attempts += 1

    if result == guess:
        print('You guessed correctly!')
        score += 1
    else:
        print('Your guess was incorrect.')

    percentCorrect = str((score / attempts) * 100) + '%'

    print("You have " + str(score) + " correct guesses in " + str(attempts) + ' attempts.')
    print("Accuracy: " + percentCorrect)
    print('Do you want to play again?')

    if input() == 'y' or 'yes':
        return coin_flip()
    else:
        quit()


coin_flip()
```

What was missing:

```
global attempts
global score
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with scoping. Either put the word `global` in front of `attemps` and `score`, or create a class (which would not be ideal for what I assume you're doing).